# $\frac{1}{n}+\ln {n}<1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n}<1+\ln{n}$ for $n\ge2$.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, upper-lower-bounds

How to prove the following bound:
$\frac{1}{n}+\ln {n}<1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n}<1+\ln{n}$ for $n\ge2$.

> My Attempt:

We have:$$\int_1^n\frac1xdx=\ln n$$So,$$\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{i+1}\le\int_1^n\frac1xdx=\ln n\le\sum_{i=1}^n\frac1i$$

Adding $1$ on both sides to get the inequality: $1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n}<1+\ln{n}$

How Can I prove the inequality given on the LHS? Also, in this case: Why is the sum $\sum_{x=1}^n\frac{1}{x}$ more than the value of the integral $\int_1^{n}\frac{1}{x}dx$? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Draw the graph, and for each rectangle between integer see what is your upper bound and what is your lower bound, and then sum them over all the intervals

Comment: Check your summation limits again. Are you sure you have $n$ intervals of length $1$, and you're comparing that against an integral over an interval of length $n-1$? Once you fix that, the rest should follow.

Comment: Re "why is the sum ... more than ..." it is related to [Riemann sums](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sum#Some_specific_types_of_Riemann_sums) and the fact that $\frac{1}{x}$ is monotone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $e^x>1+x$ for all $x>0$, we have for $k\geq 1$ that
$$
e^{\frac{1}{k}}  > 1 + \frac{1}{k} = \frac{{k + 1}}{k}.
$$
Thus
$$
e^{\sum\limits_{k = 1}^{n - 1} {\frac{1}{k}} }  > \prod\limits_{k = 1}^{n - 1} {\frac{{k + 1}}{k}}  = n,
$$
$$
\sum\limits_{k = 1}^{n - 1} {\frac{1}{k}}  > \log n,
$$
$$
\sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {\frac{1}{k}}  > \log n + \frac{1}{n}.
$$
To prove the upper bound note that
$$
\sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {\frac{1}{k}}  = 1 + \sum\limits_{k = 2}^n {\frac{1}{k}}  < 1 + \sum\limits_{k = 2}^n {\int_{k - 1}^k {\frac{{dt}}{t}} }  = 1 + \int_1^n {\frac{{dt}}{t}}  = 1 + \log n.
$$

Answer (score 2):

**Proof by example:**

[image]

The area under the hyperbola is $A=\log n$ and as $\dfrac1x$ is monotonous,

$$\tfrac12+\tfrac13+\tfrac14+\tfrac15+\tfrac16+\tfrac17+\tfrac18+\tfrac19+\tfrac1{10}<A<1+\tfrac12+\tfrac13+\tfrac14+\tfrac15+\tfrac16+\tfrac17+\tfrac18+\tfrac19.$$
The generalization to any $n$ is obvious.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the comments on this solution, OP explained that the "my attempt" is more of "I saw it in my text, but wrote it incorrectly here".

As such, my writeup would not be of much help, because I thought that OP understood what they were trying in "my attempt", and just needed a pointer on what their error was.

---

As indicated in my comment, your claim that

$$\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{i+1}\le\int_1^n\frac1xdx=\ln n\le\sum_{i=1}^n\frac1i$$

is false.

---

The true statement is

> $$\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{i+1}\le\int_1^n\frac1xdx=\ln n\le\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\frac1i.$$

---

Corollary: The desired result follows directly.

Comment: Thanks for the correction, but i would like to know how the result follows and LHS of the inequality. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: @s1mple Well, where are you stuck? From the correction, what is the next step?

Comment: How do you prove the corrected statement that you have shown. Can you please help?

Comment: How did you get your version in the first place? What principle/idea were you applying?

Comment: I saw it in my text but i wrote it here incorrectly. I wanted to how we prove these

Comment: Well, check back in your text. E.g. what section is this under? Does it talk about Riemann sums and their left/right sums as approximations, and when these are over/under?

Comment: It was just given as important inequalities, it's a book for competitive exams

Comment: Well, do the terms "Left/Right Riemann sums" mean anything to you? If yes, do you know when these are under/over estimates of the integral of the function? If no, Google it.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of the terms. Thanks for the help.